# list comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy aprendiendo python y he descubierto el concepto de "list comprehensions" (no se si tiene traducción al español).

Estaba haciendo pruebas para entenderlo y no termino de aclararme.

Por ejemplo si quiero mostrar los valores pares entre un rango de valores (0 a 25 por ejemplo), sabría hacerlo de la forma "normal" pero con este método no :(

```
pares =[]
for i in range (0,26):
    if i%2 ==0:
        pares.append(i)
print(pares)
```

Pero con "list comprehensions" no lo consigo, esta es mi última prueba,

```
pares = [x for x range(0,26) if x%2 ==0]
print (pares)
```

¡Salud y gracias!

Comment: Te faltó un `in`: `[x for x in range(0,26) if x%2==0]`. También te faltan paréntesis en el `print`, ya que tu etiqueta dice Python-3.x

Comment: @abulafia madre mía, llevaba un rato pensando porque este no me iba y no veía eso... GRACIAS. Si lo pones en las respuestas te la doy como correcta :) (ahora corrijo el print eso ha sido aquí sin querer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu enfoque era correcto, tan sólo has cometido un tonto error de sintaxis y es que te faltó el `in` que permite la iteración:

```
pares = [x for x in range(0,26) if x%2 ==0]
print (pares)
```

Aprovecho la respuesta para añadir que "*list comprehension*" se traduce oficialmente por **comprensión de listas**. Al menos así es como aparece traducido en el [tutorial oficial de python](https://tutorial.python.org.ar/en/latest/datastructures.html#comprension-de-listas). Personalmente nunca uso esa traducción porque me parece horrible y tengo la sensación de que nadie me comprenderá, pero igual son cosas mías.

Comment: Es cierto. La traducción es horrible (lista por comprehension, o comprension de listas). Lo que importa es que el código es sintácticamente más claro, ya que la instrucción literalmente indica "quiero una lista de valores para los valores en el rango de 0 a 25 donde estos valores sean pares").